Withdraw SOL from Mint Authority Account
I have some SOL in my previous mint authority address and need to recover the SOL amount. Doing normal withdraw does work.
Public Key: 5C6cHYWVy6MddjETvUawDNCESzQcKayNQCniQWPfb2z5
Balance: 0.605292 SOL
Owner: TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb
Executable: false
Rent Epoch: 18446744073709551615


Thanks for reply,
I have closed the mint account days ago using the command u mentioned. But the sol in on this address i need to recover
https://solscan.io/account/5C6cHYWVy6MddjETvUawDNCESzQcKayNQCniQWPfb2z5

did you specify the token-22 program? Seems that the close command might have failed. What was the output after running the command.

Could be possible! A lot spl-token command is failing and need to run multiple times

Assuming that there are no tokens in circulation for the provided mint account, you can use the close-mint command provided by the spl-token CLI
spl-token close-mint  --program-2022 <TOKEN_MINT_ADDRESS> 

This will close the account and return the SOL being used for rent back to you.
ref from spl docs: https://spl.solana.com/token#closing-accounts
If you mistakenly send funds to the mint and want to recover them without closing the mint account, I am unsure whether that is even possible.
